# Getting only 20 posts returned through PyTumblr

Tags: python, tumblr

I am using [PyTumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr) to return all of my posts, but it is only returning 20. I found the kwarg for the posts function, called limit, but when I specified 1000 it still returned 20. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
CLIENT = pt.TumblrRestClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET)
all_posts = CLIENT.posts(BLOG_URL, limit=1000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tumblr’s API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts) only allows to specify a limit up to 20. So your limit of 1000 is being ignored and you get 20 instead. You will have to use paging in combination with the `offset` parameter instead.

You could write yourself some generator which—similar to infinite scrolling—requests the next page as long as you keep requesting more posts from it:

```
def getAllPosts (client, blog):
    offset = 0
    while True:
        posts = client.posts(blog, limit=20, offset=offset)
        if not posts:
            return

        for post in posts:
            yield post

        offset += 20
```

Comment: @mikedidthis Thank you—if you ask me, you really wouldn’t have to delete yours though :)

Comment: No need for the duplication (I try to keep the Tumblr questions clear) and your answer is really helpful!