# How to scrape/download all tumblr images with a particular tag

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, puppeteer, tumblr, pytumblr

I am trying to download many (1000's) of images from tumblr with a particular tag (.e.g #art). I am trying to figure out the fastest and easiest way to do this. I have considered both scrapy and puppeteer as options, and I read a little bit about the tumblr API, but I'm not sure how to use the API to locally download the images I want.
Currently, puppeteer seems like the best way, but I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that tumblr uses lazy loading (e.g. what is the code for getting all the images, scrolling down, waiting for for images to load, and getting these)
Would appreciate any tips!

Comment: You may want to use the API to retrieve the links for the images, then use another program to download those images to your computer. The API is actually rather easy to use and can do the large scale collecting you want.

Comment: Thanks harada! I have never used the tumblr API, could you give me any more specific instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is below. Since I couldn't use offset, I used the timestamps of each post as an offset instead. Since I was trying to specifically get the links of images in the posts, I did a little processing of the output as well. I then used a simple python script to download every image from my list of links. I have included a website and an additional stack overflow post which I found helpful.

```
import pytumblr

def get_all_posts(client, blog):
    offset = None

    for i in range(48):
        #response = client.posts(blog, limit=20, offset=offset, reblog_info=True, notes_info=True)

        response = client.tagged('YOUR TAG HERE', limit=20, before=offset)
        for post in response:
            #    for post in response:
            if('photos' not in post):
                #print(post)
                if('body' in post):
                    body = post['body']
                    body = body.split('<')
                    body = [b for b in body if 'img src=' in b]
                    if(body):
                        body = body[0].split('"')
                        print(body[1])
                        yield body[1]
                    else:
                        yield
            else:
                print(post['photos'][0]['original_size']['url'])
                yield post['photos'][0]['original_size']['url']

        # move to the next offset
        offset = response[-1]['timestamp']
    print(offset)

client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient('USE YOUR API KEY HERE')

blog = 'staff'

# use our function
with open('{}-posts.txt'.format(blog), 'w') as out_file:
    for post in get_all_posts(client, blog):
        print(post, file=out_file)
```

Links:

https://64.media.tumblr.com/9f6b4d8d15caffe88c5877cd2fb31726/8882b6bec4975045-23/s540x810/49586f5b05e8661d77e370845d01b34f0f5f2ca6.png

[Print more than 20 posts from Tumblr API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311845/print-more-than-20-posts-from-tumblr-api)

Also thank you very much to Harada, whose advice helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the Tumblr API, so here's some instructions on how to go about that.

1. Read up on the [What You Need](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#what-you-need) section of the documentation
2. Read up on the [Get Posts With Tag](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2/#tagged--get-posts-with-tag) section
3. Consider using a library like PyTumblr

```
import pytumblr

list_of_all_posts = []

# Authenticate via OAuth
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
    'YOUR KEY HERE'
)

def get_art_posts():
    posts = client.tagged('art', **params) # returns HTML of 20 most recent posts in the tag
    # use params (shown in tumblr documentation) to change the timestamp of limit of the posts
    # i.e. to only posts before a certain time
    return posts

 list_of_all_posts.append(get_art_posts())
```

I'm pretty rusty with the Tumblr API, not gonna lie. But the documentation is kept well up to date. Once you have the HTML of the post, the link to the images will be in there. There's plenty of libraries out there like Beautiful Soup that can extract the images from the HTML by their CSS selectors. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you harada! This is very helpful. I have actually started working on a pytumblr implementation, but I am having trouble getting more than 20 posts - it seems like client.tagged doesn't have an offset parameter? when I try to add an offset, I get 'offset are not allowed fields' error. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: @gollyzoom I'm glad that pytumblr is working for you. Seems like you took care of the 20 post limit on your own too. Have fun with the project!